# What is the name for each day of the Obon Festival?

Tags: culture

The Obon festival consists of the arrival, celebration, and departure of ancestors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the usual schedule is:

Aug 13 -- [迎]{むか}え[盆]{ぼん} or [盆入]{ぼんい}り
Aug 14, 15 -- [盆]{ぼん}の[中日]{なかび} or [盆中日]{ぼんなかび}
Aug 16 -- [送]{おく}り[盆]{ぼん} or [盆明]{ぼんあ}け

---

「迎え」 and 「送り」(masu-form of 迎える/送る) mean "to welcome" and "to send off" (the spirits of the dead), respectively.
「入り」 and 「明け」 mean "the first day/beginning" and "the last day/the end" respectively.
「中日」 means "middle day".

Comment: Is Ukui and Unke only used in Okinawa? I understand Nakabi.

Comment: すみません、「うくい」「うんけ」を知らないのでわからないです。